# ACTIVESTORAGE BLOB FAILS RAILS 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, rails7

We are using rails 7 to create documents where we store files from `active_storage_blob`, right now when we migrate to rails 7 it starts to fail when we enable a key generator SHA256.

`Rails.application.config.active_support.key_generator_hash_digest_class = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256`

Now the documents hit this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method blob for nil:NilClass` in `doc.file.blob`

Any idea will be appreciated.